# How to validate SSIS packages when building Solution from commandline

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbuild

I'm investigating how to do Continuous Integration with SSIS projects.

So far I've found out that it can be done by building the solution with [devenv.exe](https://kzhendev.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/building-and-packaging-sql-server-integration-services-projects-in-teamcity/) or [MSBuild.exe](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/).

If its configured, Visual Studio can validate SSIS packages before they are run, to verify if the metadata in SSIS package is in sync with the source.

As far as I know, VS will only show validation errors/warnings when the SSIS package is open, but not when building the project.

Is it possible to have devenv.exe or MSBuild.exe also validate the packages during build?

I am using SSDT 2015 preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dtexec.exe has a /Validate option which stops excecution after the validate phase.
this could easily be scripted into your process.